# How do I show a line connecting opening brace and closing brace in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use a scheme for `IntelliJ` that shows a line connecting opening brace and closing brace for classes and methods as shown below (next to that line I draw red line).

[image]
I would like to customize another scheme and add that feature to it. However, I cannot find respective option in `Intellij`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's under Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance and it's the checkbox "show vertical indent guides"

I had a brief look for the corresponding color setting but couldn't find that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now looking for the colour setting.

Comment: It is under Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Vertical Indent Guide.

Comment: ty - but to make it easier to find it's actually settings -> editor -> color scheme -> general -> code -> vertical indent guide :)